# player only moves when screen in ACTION_DOWN or ACTIONMOVE needs to move when being touched

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

ok to i created an ontouchlistener class:

```
package drop.out.Game;

import android.view.MotionEvent;

import android.view.View;

import drop.out.Game.Model.Player;

public final class TrackingTouchListener 

 implements View.OnTouchListener{

//player class
private final Player mplayer;
Player plyr;

//constructor bringing in the player
TrackingTouchListener(Player plyr){mplayer = plyr;}

    //on touch stuff
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt) {

         /**@if touching/moving on the left side of screen */
         if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN== evt.getAction() && evt.getX() < (v.getWidth()/2) || MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE== evt.getAction() && evt.getX() <(v.getWidth()/2)){
             moveL(mplayer);
         }
         /**@if touching/moving on the right side of the screen */
         if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN== evt.getAction() && evt.getX() > (v.getWidth()/2) || MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE== evt.getAction() && evt.getX() >(v.getWidth()/2)){
             moveR(mplayer);
         } 

         return true; 
     }

     //call functions in the player class that moves the player x by -1
     private void moveL(Player player){
         player.moveL();
         //e.g. player_x -=10;
     }

     private void moveR(Player player){
         player.moveR();  
         //e.g.player_x +=10;
     }

}
```

Unfortunately the player_x is only updated when the screen is pressed or dragged across, I was hoping to have it move when the finger is on ether side of the screen.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not moving your finger, you'll stop getting updates.

Instead of calling `move` from the TouchListener, you should set a boolean flag like `shouldMove`, and then at a fixed interval issue a move command if `shouldMove` is true.

Then your character will continue to move even when you stop receiving touch events. Just clear this boolean when you lift your finger, or move out of a certain area.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just set an x value on the touchlistener then check its location to determine left or right in the main loop (like you are within the touch listener) and just set it to 0 when the finger is lifted up

edit: so

```
if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN== evt.getAction()  || MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE== evt.getAction()) 
{
    moveX = evt.getX();
}
```

then check the moveX later
and set the moveX to 0; on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP